# Python: Need a Function that Runs Only at First Time Startup

Tags: python

As the title says, I need a function that runs only the first time you use the programme. I'm making a password manager and this function is meant to create a unique encryption key for the user which would make my passwords unbreakable. I am calling this function using a button on my GUI and the way I am trying to get it to work is by using a .txt file as the memory for whether or not it's the first time.

Here is what I have:

```
def create_key():

    x = open("passfile.txt", "r")
    y = open("passfile.txt", "a")
    lines = x.readlines()
    for s in lines:
        if "nofirst" in s:
            pass
        else:
            a = str(randint(1,8))
            b = str(randint(1,9))
            c = str(randint(1,10))
            d = str(randint(1,11))
            e = str(randint(1,12))
            f = str(randint(1,13))
            g = str(randint(1,14))
            h = str(randint(1,15))
            i = str(randint(1,16))
            j = str([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i])
            k = ''.join(j)            
            tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Enigma wants you to know:", "Please memorize or write this code down:" + k)
            y.write("nofirst" + "\n")
```

I've been fiddling with this one piece of code for about a about a week now and it still has several problems:

1. when the dialogue pops up telling you to memorize the key, it keeps on popping up again and again each time with a different key and it repeats about 10 times.
2. although it adds nofirst to passfile.txt, it goes ahead and runs the function every time i press the button anyway.

   I would appreciate if you guys could tell me why these problems are occurring and give me a replacement function to use.

Comment: I think I just cringed a little at the idea of making anything security-related without using secure random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for the existence of the file first; only create it if it doesn't yet exist otherwise read the data:

```
_here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def create_key():    
    filename = os.path.join(_here, 'passfile.txt')
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        # exists
        with open(filename) as passfile:
            secret = passfile.read().strip()
    else:
        # create a new key
        secret = ''.join([str(randint(1, i + 8)) for i in range(8)])
        with open(filename, 'w') as passfile:
            secret = passfile.write(secret)
```

You really want to use an absolute filename here (full path) and not rely on where your script was started. This is what the `_here` variable provides, the directory name of the current file. With it we make a filename for the password file, which you can then test against with `os.path.isfile()`.

Comment: thanks, but your answer is not helpful in my situation. I want the specific to be run only at first startup not only once at startup. i.e, the first day the person uses my programme, they are given a key. the next day, they are asked for that key (so if nofirst is found in passfile.txt, it asks them for a key)

Comment: I think the question was looking for something that persists between runs of the program, hence the use of a file.

Comment: I'll follow up later then; test if the file *exists*, if not generate it.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thankyou. One last thing, I would really appreciate it, if you could explain to me which part of your given code actually creates a file, upon seeing that one doesn't exist.

Comment: When the file doesn't exist, `os.path.isfile()` returns `False` and the `else:` branch is executed. Opening a file for writing (`open(filename, 'w')`) creates the file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `pass` in your loop. That command by definition doesn't do anything.  Use the command `break` instead to exit the loop when you see `nofirst`.

Comment: Thank's for the reply. Tried that, but it makes practically no difference, except now only repeating twice instead of five times. But i don't even want this to be a loop. I want it to run once and only once.

Comment: Is `nofirst` the first line in your file?

Comment: yes it is, though it's also written later, everytime i press that button which i've linked the function to.

Comment: If you don't want it to be a loop, then why did you write a loop? Please be clear and explicit about your exact intended logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I have for you, maybe not the cleanest but it works. Took this as an opportunity for me to poke at serialization in Python so these may not be the best practices.

```
import pickle
import os

def create_key():
    #First check to see if the property files exists
    filePath = 'C:/------FILEPATH-------/'
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        #check to see that the file is not blank
        if os.stat(filePath)[6] > 0:
            #If it is not, load the firstRun variable
            with open(filePath, 'rb') as f:
                firstRun = pickle.load(f)
        else:
            with open(filePath, 'wb') as f:
                firstRun = 't'
                pickle.dump(firstRun,f)   
    else:
        #If it does not, create the file and save the firstRun variable as true,
        #since it has to be the first run if the file doesn't exist
        with open(filePath, 'wb') as f:
            firstRun = 't'
            pickle.dump(firstRun,f)    

    if firstRun == 't':

        '''
        Put key generation code here
        '''

        #Since the key has been generated we no longer want to do this so we set
        #firstRun to false and save the property file
        with open(filePath, 'wb') as f:
            firstRun = 'f'
            pickle.dump(firstRun,f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_key()      
    print('done!')
```